# Как изменить ссылку на предоставляемом сайте?

Tags: html

Проблема в следующем. Некая CRM система предоставляет сайт. На этом сайте есть кнопка, например, "Оплатить счета", которая переводит в личный кабинет. Нужно чтобы ссылка кнопки перенаправляла на сторонний сайт. В самой CRM-ке под каждого менять не собираются, но в настройках можно добавить код внутри тега head (прям так и написано и поле для кода), т.е. менять нельзя, но добавлять можно, а также прикреплять CSS и JS файлы.
Блок кнопки выглядит так:

```
<div class="flex valign link payment nowrap">
    <a href="..........."></a>
    <div>
        <div class="main-links__title">Оплатить счета</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я так понимаю, что нужно сначала прописать отмену этой ссылки, а затем в этот блок прописать свою ссылку. В этом я совсем не силен... Кто знает , как это можно сделать, поделитесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу, то нужно прописать скрипт, который при клике на ссылку/кнопку будет отменять переход по умолчанию и задавать новый адрес для перехода (решение на jQuery):

```
$('.link.payment a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open('/* здесь адрес, куда надо переходить */');
});
```

Comment: Вроде должно сработать, но я так понимаю, в самом теле нужно подгружать такой скрипт из файла, вроде такого: <script type="text/javascript" src="........................./js/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>

Comment: Почему из файла? Можно в тегах <script></script> его прямо в html прописать. Главное, чтобы jquery было подключено на сайте. Либо его надо подключить.